# How to check if value of input is empty after browser refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all inputs with class "chang" that contain any value after browser refresh, but entered by the user before refreshing. I tried few things, and nothing works. It's my HTML code:

```
<input class="chang" id="test1" /> <input class="chang" id="test2" />
```

And script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if( $(".chang").val().length != 0 ) {
$(this).hide();
}

});
```

I tried to make it works in Firefox (if it's matter). What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is. In this scope, it refers to the `document` object.

Comment: What do you mean by "but entered by the user before refreshing" ?

Comment: I meant when in html this input is empty, without predefined value, and user entered a new value into this input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.chang').each(function(index){
  if($(this).val().length != 0){
   $(this).hide();
  }
 });
});
```

Use each() to iterate multiple elements with same class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the value of the input is empty like this:

```
if( $(".chang").val() == "" ) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7w2Wr/7/)

Comment: Should be `$('.chang').hide();` not `$(this).hide();`. In your case `this` will point to `document`, not `input`

Comment: @antyrat thx for you comment but in that case it hides all inputs with that class. That if statement should be in each function like my fiddle example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".chang").each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length != 0) { 
        $(this).hide(); 
    }
});
```

It iterates over each of the `.chang` elements allowing you to use the `$(this)` correctly
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/4RXe5/)**

Comment: Yes, I needed to use `each`. Thanks for advice, works perfect.